# Run-time error '13' type mismatch: Excel if else statment

Tags: vba, excel

The *** indicates where excel highlights when I get my error.  If I put the first command right after my else statement (on the same line) it will run once.  Then it gives the same error on the second run.  Then I put it down on the next line, and it errors again.  Please help.

```
Sub Average_Var_Page()
Z = 6
PS1 = 0
PS = 0

Do
If Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value = 0 Then
    GoTo ZPLUSPS
Else
 ***PS = PS + Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value****
    PS1 = PS1 + 1
End If

ZPLUSPS:
Z = Z + 1

Loop Until IsEmpty(Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z))

X = PS / PS1
Application.Worksheets("EACHsTEPVAR").Range("P1").Value = X


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the following a try, and see if it makes any difference!
It ensures that you are adding the same type, and should hopefully preserve your formula.

```
Sub Average_Var_Page()
Z = 6
PS1 = 0
PS = 0

Y = Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value

Do
If Y = 0 Then
    GoTo ZPLUSPS
    Else
    PS = PS + Val(Y)
    PS1 = PS1 + 1
End If

ZPLUSPS:
Z = Z + 1

Loop Until IsEmpty(Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z))

X = PS / PS1
Application.Worksheets("EACHsTEPVAR").Range("P1").Value = X


End Sub
```

Comment: If I move the Y = Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value into the loop this worked!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to make sure your value is a number before adding it. Try using something like the IsNumeric function

```
  If IsNumeric(Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value) Then
  PS = PS + Application.Worksheets("EachStepVar").Range("E" & Z).Value
  End If
```

You could also try CInt() function, if Excel is somehow interpreting a number as text.